# JSON into Access

Tags: json

I am a student at Philipps Marburg, Germany. I am doing research in Political Economics and some of the data that I need is stored in JSON files.
I do not have ANY experience doing programming in VBA, C++, Python, etc., but I need to download this data into an easy to search database: Access, Stata, or I'm open to using a programming language to manipulate it in order to identify the speicific fields that I need before putting it into an Access, Google spreadsheet, Excel, Stata software package.

I don't even know where to begin. I have downloaded Cygwin, Gitshell, and Github; but I am clueless as to how to begin to use them.

The data I need can be retrieved in one of two places:
https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki

or

https://www.govtrack.us/developers/data

I am going to do whatever it takes to download this data and put into a searchable database, but if someone could help me to get started that would be super GREAT!

Comment: if you have the json code available search on google for 'json to csv converter' then paste the csv code into notepad, save as data.csv then open from the excel open menu ;)

Comment: Thank you David. I was thinking to go that route except it is really a lot of data that I need to download (e.g. I need all of the following https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/112/bills/hr/)

Comment: /congress/bills already sounds like a lot of data. seems like you will need to go into each address and access data.json file. that file isnt so large to covert online, but will take a while to go through the list. Maybe pay someone on Freelancer or oDesk to do it.... Or you could write a scraper that fetches, converts, and stores the data into an excel readable format